# Performing a server-query via an img tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, cross-domain

*Disclaimer: This is more of a general interest question rather than something I am actually considering doing, since there are less hacky ways to achieve the same thing.*

But, out of curiosity:

I can create custom `<img ...>` tags with JavaScript, which the browser will go and fetch. By choosing the URL for the `src` attribute of the image appropriately, this technically allows me to execute arbitrary server queries if my web server doesn't just return a static image file for the url-request, but actually processes it via some form of `GET`-servlet.

The beauty of this is that it can be used for cross-domain requests in pretty much any browser that supports images without opening yourself up for any of the vulnerabilities that [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) would, for example.

The problem is that I cannot return any data from this sort of server query, since the cross-domain policies usually block any sort of pixel-access to the image...

Or can I?

I should be able to at least return two small unsigned integers in the range of 1 to maybe 1000  or more by generating a blank image with a certain width and height, which the browser then allows me to retrieve no matter where the image was loaded from, correct?

Are there other such tricks I can use to send even more information along with the image? And what limitations would I face in trying to get at the information?

As an example, could the server set a cookie when returning the image? If so, I could probably only access that cookie from the same domain, right? So it wouldn't be useful for cross-site-scripting (except if the client doesn't need to care about the info in the cookie, but the server does).

Or could I, as another example, somehow change the image's `src` by having the server reply with a redirect in such a way that I can retrieve the redirect-target in JavaScript?

Crazy ideas welcome! ;)

**NOTE:**

This question is **not** meant as very broad (received close request?!?): There are only a very limited number of properties that an HTML `img` tag has that could be manipulated by a server and then read by a client. Image width and height might in fact be the only ones (at least I couldn't find any others). I'm just asking whether there are more. There should only be very few other properties out there, if any.

Comment: Shady things like this are done all the time for tracking and advertising purposes. See [Wiki: Web beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon). And yes, this does help bypass client-side cross-domain request limitations.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Usually these only send data (or even just a ping) from the page/email to the server, though. I'm wondering whether I could also retrieve data from a server this way.

Comment: No, not easily. You could embed information in an image and extract it with JavaScript or something, but... ew, and browser security is pretty tough. You may be stopped dead in your tracks by most browsers these days.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Sending two integers via the image's width and height should be possible in all browsers, though, correct? Are there maybe other hacks like this?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be one way. You could look more into [Wiki: Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) and libraries like [steganography.js](http://www.peter-eigenschink.at/projects/steganographyjs/showcase/) to really abuse this.

Comment: At one time one other piece of information could be obtained: how long it takes for the image to load. I have seen some who use this to attempt to determine private IP addresses the client machine can access: create a bunch of img tags for various local addresses and see how long each takes. A short load time indicates a listening machine. Pretty sure this has now been restricted by most browsers.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ The problem is that the browser usually doesn't give me access to the image's pixel-data (definitely not if the image is from a cross-domain source), so encoding any information in the actual image will not be possible.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I wonder how many bits of data one could transfer like this. Definitely, over a slow mobile connection, one would have to load several calibration-images in parallel to have any shot at even being able to send a single bit. But in a wired environment, this might give you an extra maybe 3-8 bits... :) I guess the biggest issue might be the delay it introduces into the requests, and since many browsers only allow two parallel downloads, it could really kill the user-experience...